# what happens to a mutex object if not released by parent applicaiton

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

I have a named mutex in my application.

```
 private Mutex TaskExitStatus = new Mutex(false, "TaskExit")
```

I acquire the mutex in a method using TaskExitStatus.WaitOne()

What will happen if I am not releasing the mutex while exiting the application? Will the mutex be disposed safely?

**Update 1:**
Will both named and unnamed mutex behave the same when not released on application exit?

**Update 2**
This is what i read from [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Use the CloseHandle function to close the handle. The system closes
>   the handle automatically when the process terminates. The mutex object
>   is destroyed when its last handle has been closed.

Comment: It makes a loud bang.  AbandonedMutexException.  Don't catch it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx), it is abandoned (not necessarily disposed)

> If a thread terminates while owning a mutex, the mutex is said to be abandoned

Also, heed the warning about abandoned Mutexes:

> An abandoned mutex often indicates a serious error in the code. When a thread exits without releasing the mutex, the data structures protected by the mutex might not be in a consistent state. The next thread to request ownership of the mutex can handle this exception and proceed, if the integrity of the data structures can be verified.

Comment: @Rockstart yes, an unnamed mutex is essentially a "local" mutex. Therefore, can only be accessed from threads within the same process. If your application is exited then your mutex is abandoned, however, you should be ok in this scenario as no other threads can access it anyway. You should try and release it more gracefully if you can though...

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a Mutex is to maintain a lock (for named Mutexes across applications) until it is released. If you do not release the Mutex the lock should be maintained on the resource until the computer is rebooted.

Comment: Please disregard - James is right. I was thinking it was different for a named Mutex, but it is not. The only difference is the next thread obtaining the lock in the case of a named Mutex will get an exception thrown.